# JSON to MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I know there are lot of similar questions but I tried some answers from there, but my case still not working.
I'm trying to pass my Json data to MVC controller, but the controller is never called. Any idea?

Ajax call:

```
 function getContentModelFromController(onsuccess) {
    
         var chunks = [{
            content: $('#ir-content').text(),
            lang: "en",
            mimeType: "text/plain"
        }];

        var content = {
            title: $('#ir-title').text(),
            chunks: chunks
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "@Url.Action("GetContentModelForReaderAsync","Home")",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(content),
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result, status) {
                onsuccess(result, status);
                console.log('GetContentModelForReaderAsync WORKED ');
            },
            error: function (result, status) {
                console.log('GetContentModelForReaderAsync ' + result.status);
                console.log('GetContentModelForReaderAsync ' + status);
            }
        });
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Chunk {
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string mimeType { get; set; }
}

public async Task<JsonResult> GetContentModelForReaderAsync(
            List<Chunk> chunks, string title
            )
        {
           .....
        }
```

Comment: Have you looked in developer tools in the browser to see what actually happens?

Comment: Open the developer tools with F12, go to the [Network] tab and look for any requests. There will probably be a 404 or 500 error, since your endpoint is not being called. You can also look at the javascript code from the dev console, and ensure that MVC is putting the correct URL into your code.

Comment: Yes, it goes to error section with 404 result.status

Comment: Pls post your route configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

create view model

```
public class ChunkViewModel {
  public  List<Chunk> Chunks {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

action

```
[Route("~/Home/GetContentModelForReaderAsync")]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetContentModelForReaderAsync([FromBody] ChunkViewModel viewModel)
 {
           .....
 }
```